# Extjs drag and drop single item on grid with checkbox model

Tags: javascript, extjs, checkbox, drag-and-drop, grid

I modified the following example code to checkbox model.  Here is the link
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.DragDrop

Two questions, first:
When dragging an item, all the selected items are being moved too. How to drag only one item each time?

Another question:
When dragging an item, it is forced to become selected. How to make it remain state unchange? (keep unselected when it is unselected before the drag, and vice versa)

And I am using version 4.2.1.

Here is the code modified from the given example:

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
    Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        storeId: 'simpsonsStore',
        fields: ['name'],
        data: [
            ["Lisa"],
            ["Bart"],
            ["Homer"],
            ["Marge"]
        ],
        proxy: {
            type: 'memory',
            reader: 'array'
        }
    });

    Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        store: 'simpsonsStore',
        selModel: {mode: 'SIMPLE'}, //added
        selType: 'checkboxmodel', //added
        columns: [{
            header: 'Name',
            dataIndex: 'name',
            flex: true
        }],
        viewConfig: {
            plugins: {
                ptype: 'gridviewdragdrop',
                dragText: 'Drag and drop to reorganize'
            }
        },
        height: 200,
        width: 400,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You need to overwrite the dragZone in the DragDrop plugin, so it is only sending this record.
2. the drag has a mousedown event, which is selecting the rows in the grid (because this has a mousedown event too), so it's fired before drag ends.

To understand this I explain this events (for more info [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp):

1. row selection event: this is a **mousedown** event on a grid row.
2. row `drag` event: **drag = mousepress +** (optional) **mousemove**, BUT: mousepress doesn't really exist so it decides it with the help of time between mousedown and mouseup

   - the time measurement is done with delayedTasks
   - if mouseup fired before the delayed time, then it will not be executed, else drag starts
3. row `drop` event: **drop = dragged + mouseup**

   There are more ways to prevent this:

   1. try to put the selection to another event, which is fired after drag starts, but it can be messy because this event is used lots of times...
   2. it's selecting it on mousedown, but we deselect it on drag start event and at drop we prevent the selection, **I do this in the code**.

The working code:

```js
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId:'simpsonsStore',
    fields:['name'],
    data: [["Lisa"], ["Bart"], ["Homer"], ["Marge"]],
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: 'array'
    }
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    store: 'simpsonsStore',
    selModel: {mode: 'SIMPLE'}, //added
    selType: 'checkboxmodel', //added
    columns: [
        {header: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name', flex: true}
    ],
    viewConfig: {
        plugins: {
            ptype: 'gridviewdragdrop',
            dragText: 'Drag and drop to reorganize',
            onViewRender : function(view) {
                var me = this,
                    scrollEl;
                if (me.enableDrag) {
                    if (me.containerScroll) {
                        scrollEl = view.getEl();
                    }                   
                    me.dragZone = new Ext.view.DragZone({
                        view: view,
                        ddGroup: me.dragGroup || me.ddGroup,
                        dragText: me.dragText,
                        containerScroll: me.containerScroll,
                        scrollEl: scrollEl,
                        //to remember if the row was selected originally or not
                        onBeforeDrag: function(data, e) {                            
                            var me = this,                               
                                view = data.view,
                                selectionModel = view.getSelectionModel(),
                                record = view.getRecord(data.item);
                            if (!selectionModel.isSelected(record)) {
                                data.rowSelected = false;
                            } 
                            return true;
                        },

                        onInitDrag: function(x, y) {
                            var me = this,
                                data = me.dragData,
                                view = data.view,
                                selectionModel = view.getSelectionModel(),
                                record = view.getRecord(data.item);
                            //for deselect the dragged record
                            if (selectionModel.isSelected(record) && data.rowSelected == false) {
                                selectionModel.deselect(record, true);                                
                            }
                            //added the original row so it will handle that in the drag drop
                            data.records = [record];                            
                            me.ddel.update(me.getDragText());
                            me.proxy.update(me.ddel.dom);
                            me.onStartDrag(x, y);
                            return true;
                        }
                    });
                }

                if (me.enableDrop) {
                    me.dropZone = new Ext.grid.ViewDropZone({
                        view: view,
                        ddGroup: me.dropGroup || me.ddGroup,
                        //changed the selection at the end of this method
                        handleNodeDrop : function(data, record, position) {
                            var view = this.view,
                                store = view.getStore(),
                                index, records, i, len;

                            if (data.copy) {
                                records = data.records;
                                data.records = [];
                                for (i = 0, len = records.length; i < len; i++) {
                                    data.records.push(records[i].copy());
                                }
                            } else {                                
                                data.view.store.remove(data.records, data.view === view);
                            }                    
                            if (record && position) {
                                index = store.indexOf(record);
                                if (position !== 'before') {
                                    index++;
                                }
                                store.insert(index, data.records);
                            }                            
                            else {
                                store.add(data.records);
                            }
                            if (view != data.view) {
                                view.getSelectionModel().select(data.records);
                            }                                                   
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }        
    },
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Comment: It works. Although there is a moment that the select state changes, and changes back immediately. More important it works. Thanks!

Comment: Amazing, you've saved my day. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Alexander's reply. After reading his reply, I get into the related source code of Extjs. And finally solved the problem of changing state back immediately instead of keep it remains unchange. The code:

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
    Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        storeId: 'simpsonsStore',
        fields: ['name'],
        data: [
            ["Lisa"],
            ["Bart"],
            ["Homer"],
            ["Marge"]
        ],
        proxy: {
            type: 'memory',
            reader: 'array'
        }
    });

    Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        store: 'simpsonsStore',
        /* Start: Code block added to the original example */
        selModel: {mode: 'SIMPLE', onRowMouseDown: Ext.emptyFn /* throw away onRowMouseDown handler to answer Q2 */},
        selType: 'checkboxmodel', 
        listeners: {
            afterrender: function(){
                /* override the original handleNodeDrop function to answer Q1 */
                this.view.plugins[0].dropZone.handleNodeDrop = function(data, record, position) {
                    var view = this.view,
                    store = view.getStore(),
                    index, records, i, len;

                    if (data.copy) {
                        records = data.records;
                        data.records = [];
                        for (i = 0, len = records.length; i < len; i++) {
                            data.records.push(records[i].copy());
                        }
                    } else {
                        data.view.store.remove(data.records, data.view === view);
                    }

                    if (record && position) {
                        index = store.indexOf(record);

                        if (position !== 'before') {
                            index++;
                        }
                        store.insert(index, data.records);
                    }
                    else {
                        store.add(data.records);
                    }

                    // view.getSelectionModel().select(data.records);
                };
                /* override the original onInitDrag function to answer Q2 */
                this.view.plugins[0].dragZone.onInitDrag = function(x, y){
                    var me = this,
                    data = me.dragData,
                    view = data.view,
                    selectionModel = view.getSelectionModel(),
                    record = view.getRecord(data.item);

                    // if (!selectionModel.isSelected(record)) {
                        // selectionModel.select(record, true);
                    // }
                    // data.records = selectionModel.getSelection();
                    data.records = [selectionModel.lastFocused];

                    me.ddel.update(me.getDragText());
                    me.proxy.update(me.ddel.dom);
                    me.onStartDrag(x, y);
                    return true;
                };
            }
        }, 
        /* End: Code block added to the original example */
        columns: [{
            header: 'Name',
            dataIndex: 'name',
            flex: true
        }],
        viewConfig: {
            plugins: {
                ptype: 'gridviewdragdrop',
                dragText: 'Drag and drop to reorganize'
            }
        },
        height: 200,
        width: 400,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
});
```

Comment: But with this solution the checkbox check isn't working. The main problem is that the row selection (which includes the checkbox click too) event is starting with mousedown event and the drag is starting with mousedown too...

Comment: Thanks for your reply again. Actually, I face the same problem when importing ExtJS 4.1.1 (the real task is running under version 4.1.1), while the code is written for ExtJS 4.2.1. My conclusion is that Sencha added onRowClick event for checkbox model in 4.2, and this makes the difference. Here is JSFiddle link for you interest. http://jsfiddle.net/W5r8d/

Comment: What is the difference? Still have the problem of changing state back instead of remaining unchanged. My solution on version 4.1.1 is to separate onRowMouseDown to two functions and register as itemMouseDown and itemClick event handler of the grid view. I did not clean it up as readable example code, so not put it here :)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested in 4.1.1 Solution here is the modified Alexander's code that keeps previously selected rows selected after drop.

I slightly modified onInitDrag to select already-selected row back on drag start,
and handleNodeDrop to get it selected on drop.

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId:'simpsonsStore',
    fields:['name'],
    data: [["Lisa"], ["Bart"], ["Homer"], ["Marge"]],
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: 'array'
    }
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    store: 'simpsonsStore',
    selModel: {mode: 'SIMPLE'}, //added
    selType: 'checkboxmodel', //added
    columns: [
        {header: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name', flex: true}
    ],
    resizable: true,
    viewConfig: {
        plugins: {
            ptype: 'gridviewdragdrop',
            dragText: 'Drag and drop to reorganize',
            onViewRender : function(view) {
                var me = this,
                    scrollEl;
                if (me.enableDrag) {
                    if (me.containerScroll) {
                        scrollEl = view.getEl();
                    }                   
                    me.dragZone = new Ext.view.DragZone({
                        view: view,
                        ddGroup: me.dragGroup || me.ddGroup,
                        dragText: me.dragText,
                        containerScroll: me.containerScroll,
                        scrollEl: scrollEl,
                        //to remember if the row was selected originally or not
                        onBeforeDrag: function(data, e) {                            
                            var me = this,                               
                                view = data.view,
                                selectionModel = view.getSelectionModel(),
                                record = view.getRecord(data.item);
                            if (!selectionModel.isSelected(record)) {
                                data.rowSelected = false;
                            } else {
                                data.rowSelected = true;
                            }
                            return true;
                        },

                        onInitDrag: function(x, y) {
                            var me = this,
                                data = me.dragData,
                                view = data.view,
                                selectionModel = view.getSelectionModel(),
                                record = view.getRecord(data.item);
                            //to deselect the dragged record
                            if (selectionModel.isSelected(record) && data.rowSelected == false) {
                                selectionModel.deselect(record, true); 
                            } else {
                                selectionModel.select(record, true); 
                            }
                            //added the original row so it will handle that in the drag drop
                            data.records = [record];                            
                            me.ddel.update(me.getDragText());
                            me.proxy.update(me.ddel.dom);
                            me.onStartDrag(x, y);
                            
                            return true;
                        }
                    });
                }

                if (me.enableDrop) {
                    me.dropZone = new Ext.grid.ViewDropZone({
                        view: view,
                        ddGroup: me.dropGroup || me.ddGroup,
                        //changed the selection at the end of this method
                        handleNodeDrop : function(data, record, position) {
                            var view = this.view,
                                store = view.getStore(),
                                selectionModel = view.getSelectionModel(),
                                index, records, i, len;

                            if (data.copy) {
                                records = data.records;
                                data.records = [];
                                for (i = 0, len = records.length; i < len; i++) {
                                    data.records.push(records[i].copy());
                                }
                            } else {                                
                                data.view.store.remove(data.records, data.view === view);
                            }        
                            
                            if (record && position) {
                                index = store.indexOf(record);
                                if (position !== 'before') {
                                    index++;
                                 }
                                store.insert(index, data.records);
                            }                            
                            else {
                                store.add(data.records);
                            }
                            
                            //select row back on drop if it was selected
                            if (data.rowSelected) {
                                selectionModel.select(data.records, true);
                            }

                            if (view != data.view) {
                                view.getSelectionModel().select(data.records);
                            }          
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }        
    },
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

PS: easiest way to test - https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor
just select 4.1.1 and copy-paste.